# Label PGFPlot table points with coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, labels, pgfplotstable, coordinates

I would like to label each plotted point with its x and y coordinate. I am able to label with a single one using the MWE below. I must avoid manually labeling each point since my actual table size is larger and will be changed out regularly.

```
\documentclass{standalone} 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=&,row sep=\\]{
 x     &  y     \\
 0.940 &  0.992 \\
 0.992 & -0.940 \\
-0.992 &  0.940 \\
-0.940 & -0.992 \\
}\mytable

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}
    \addplot+[only marks, nodes near coords]table[x=x,y=y,meta=x]{\mytable};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which creates the following figure
[image: sample figure]

The desired output is for each point to be labelled with both coordinates. For specific example the top left point would be labelled with "(0.94, 0.992)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{standalone} 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=&,row sep=\\]{
 x     &  y     \\
 0.940 &  0.992 \\
 0.992 & -0.940 \\
-0.992 &  0.940 \\
-0.940 & -0.992 \\
}\mytable

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[enlargelimits=0.3]
    \addplot+[only marks,
    visualization depends on={x \as \myx},
    visualization depends on={y \as \myy},
     nodes near coords={$(\myx,\myy)$}]table[x=x,y=y]{\mytable};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [PGFPlots manual (v1.17) section 8.6 on page 553](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#page=553).

To change the number format of the output have a look at the [TikZ manual (v3.1.7) section 97 (page 1051)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf#page=1051), e.g. if you want to output 3 decimal numbers instead of only 2.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.17
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotstableread{
         x      y
         0.940  0.992
         0.992 -0.940
        -0.992  0.940
        -0.940 -0.992
    }\mytable
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        only marks,
        nodes near coords={%
            $(\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x}},
              \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}})$%
        },
    ]
        \addplot table [x=x,y=y] {\mytable};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Thanks for adding references!